# Buffer Overrun Exception by fscanf_s

Tags: c++

Following openGL beginner tutorials, I've finished writing my own loader of .OBJ files. After writing, a process of compilation usually follows, which is tiresome and disgusting in C++. I've encountered an unhandled exception in one of my methods, here is the code:

```
float* Loader::LoadObj(const char* filePath){
//Declaration of v, vt and vn temporary container buffers for parsing
vector<glm::vec3> vertcies;
vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
vector<glm::vec3> normals;
vector<fvert> facevertcies;

//open the file
FILE* objFile;
fopen_s(&objFile, filePath,"r");
if( objFile == NULL )
{
    printf("Impossible to open the file ! Are you in the right path ?\n");
}

            char line[128]; // where to store the first string read from each line

            //other containers
            glm::vec3 vertex;
            glm::vec2 uv;
            glm::vec3 normal;
            fvert fv1,fv2,fv3;

            // for each line in the obj file
            while(true)
            {

                // read the first word of the line
                int lineId = fscanf_s(objFile,"%s",line);                   
                        if (lineId == EOF)  
                            break;
                // parse line by line
                if ( strcmp( line, "v" ) == 0 )
                {
                        fscanf_s(objFile, "%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
                        vertcies.push_back(vertex);                             
                }
                else if ( strcmp( line, "vt" ) == 0 )
                {       
                        fscanf_s(objFile, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y);
                        uvs.push_back(uv);                          
                }
                else if ( strcmp( line, "vn" ) == 0 )
                {
                        fscanf_s(objFile,"%f %f %f\n", &normal.x, &normal.y, &normal.z );
                        normals.push_back(normal);
                }... //method continues}}
```

Code is not complete, but its other parts are irrelevant. LoadObj(char*) method attempts to open an obj file and then enters a while loop iterating through all the lines of the file for parsing. With breakpoints I managed to deduce that the "stack buffer overrun" exception occurs at the first call of fscanf_s  in the loop (file opens soundly tho). I tried to catch it with empty try catch, unsuccessfully.

Could someone, please, help me understand what causes this exception and maybe complement their answer with a solution. This is my first post on this forum, hope I didn't break any rules here. Please, help a newbie. This is the CallStack.

```
    XXX.exe!__report_gsfailure(unsigned __int64 StackCookie) Line 147   C
XXX.exe!__GSHandlerCheckCommon(void * EstablisherFrame, _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT * DispatcherContext, _GS_HANDLER_DATA * GSHandlerData) Line 189 C
XXX.exe!__GSHandlerCheck_EH(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, void * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT * DispatcherContext) Line 96    C
ntdll.dll!000007fc400f9f4d()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!000007fc400fb220()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!000007fc400e4bba()    Unknown
msvcr110d.dll!memset() Line 161 Unknown
msvcr110d.dll!_input_s_l(_iobuf * stream, const unsigned char * format, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo, char * arglist) Line 939  C++
msvcr110d.dll!vfscanf(int (_iobuf *, const unsigned char *, localeinfo_struct *, char *) * inputfn, _iobuf * stream, const char * format, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo, char * arglist) Line 62 C
msvcr110d.dll!fscanf_s(_iobuf * stream, const char * format, ...) Line 132  C
```

Bonus Question: I also read here http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/02/two-safer-alternatives-to-scanf/  that my code can be improved by using char* instead of fixed char array and passing %ms to fscanf, which dynamically allocates memory for storage. Can someone show me, how to implement it in my code? The possibility is attractive, despite the fact I can't even get the damn original to run. Thanks heaps to those who'll be able to help.

Comment: technically, fscanf is not a C++ function. It is a C function. You could use [iostreams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) and [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `FILE` (and related functions). If I remember correctly, *.obj is a bunch of numbers/strings separated by whitespace. It'll be easier to read something like that using iostreams instead of using C-style functions and dealing with buffer overruns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int lineId = fscanf_s(objFile,"%s",line);
```

should likely be changed to:

```
int lineId = fscanf_s(objFile,"%s",line,sizeof(line));
```

So much for secure versions... :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! Funny thing is I tried it before and it didn't. I don't assume this will work with char* and %ms, since it's size is not yet specified. I can't vote your answer up, coz I'm lacking reputation points. As soon as I get 15, I'll give you credit.